# replace dataframe values based on another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe which is structured as follows:

```
             timestamp       y
0 2020-01-01 00:00:00   336.0
1 2020-01-01 00:15:00   544.0
2 2020-01-01 00:30:00   736.0
3 2020-01-01 00:45:00   924.0
4 2020-01-01 01:00:00  1260.0
...
```

The `timestamp` column is a datetime data type

and I have another dataframe with the following structure:

```
                     y
timestamp
00:00:00    625.076923
00:15:00    628.461538
00:30:00    557.692308
00:45:00    501.692308
01:00:00    494.615385
...
```

I this case, the time is the pandas datetime index.

Now what I want to do is replace the values in the first dataframe where the time field is matching i.e. the time of the day is matching with the second dataset.

Comment: what's the dtype of your timestamp columns?

Comment: @NoobVB I have updated the question a bit regarding the types. In first case, it is a column with datetime[ns] type and in the second case it is an index.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC your first dataframe df1's timestamp is `datetime` type and your second dataframe (df2) has an index of type `datetime` as well but only time and not date.

then you can do:

```
df1['y'] = df1['timestamp'].dt.time.map(df2['y'])
```

Comment: This really is some next level voodoo!

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't be surprised if there is a better way, but you can accomplish this by working to get the tables so that they can `merge` on the time. Assuming your dataframes will be `df` and `df2`.

```py
df['time'] = df['timestamp'].dt.time
df2 = df2.reset_index()
df2['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df2['timestamp'].dt.time
df_combined = pd.merge(df,df2,left_on='time',right_on='timestamp')
df_combined
    timestamp_x           y_x   time      timestamp_y   y_y
0   2020-01-01 00:00:00 336.0   00:00:00    00:00:00    625.076923
1   2020-01-01 00:15:00 544.0   00:15:00    00:15:00    628.461538
2   2020-01-01 00:30:00 736.0   00:30:00    00:30:00    557.692308
3   2020-01-01 00:45:00 924.0   00:45:00    00:45:00    501.692308
4   2020-01-01 01:00:00 1260.0  01:00:00    01:00:00    494.615385
# This clearly has more than you need, so just keep what you want and rename things back.

df_combined = df_combined[['timestamp_x','y_y']]
df_combined = df_combined.rename(columns={'timestamp_x':'timestamp','y_y':'y'})
```

Answer (score 1):

New answer I like way better: actually using `.map()`

Still need to get df2 to have the time column to match on.

```py
df2 = df2.reset_index()
df2['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df2['timestamp'].dt.time
df['y'] = df['timestamp'].dt.time.map(dict(zip(df2['timestamp',df2['y'])))
```